# Use of php function in clause where of sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need your help please, i tried to resolve this but no success.
I need to select 3 fields from my table like so:

I have a predefined function :

```
function get_lastname_by_name($name){
   // traitements
   return $lastname;
}
```

And i have the query :

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, lastname FROM table WHERE name = "///See next query ///";
```

The problem is that I need to use the function get_lastname_by_name ()  with name as a parameter , the query will be as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, lastname FROM table WHERE name = ".get_lastname_by_name (name);
```

get_lastname_by_name (name) retrieve the lastname by a call to an epp server

I know that this is impossible because name is not a variable or a valid paramétre, but i'm trying to found how to resolve it and I thought to share this issue with your community because it is the best on the web.

Comment: What is your get_lastname_by_name() function supposed to return?

Comment: What database layer are you using? If it supports prepared statements this isn't hard to answer: Just bind the result of the function to a placeholder.

Comment: @MarkBaker get_lastname_by_name($name) return a lastname that i must compare with the lastname in sql query

Comment: I mean, how do you get that lastname, what does the get_lastname_by_name() do to actually generate that lastname from name?

Comment: Does your function use a query to retrieve last name using name as parameter ?

Comment: @tadman If i understand ur question the database layer that i use is Mysql

Comment: @MarkBaker It connect to an epp server and retrieve the lastname by name from the server.

Comment: @Alex no it retrieve the lastname by a call to an epp server

Comment: The *database* you use is MySQL. The driver layer is typically `mysql_query`, PDO or `mysqli`. At the very least you should be using PDO.